# Estoy haciendo una app en node js y estoy haciendo las pruebas en postman

Tags: nodejs, postman, split

Estoy haciendo una app en node js y estoy haciendo las pruebas en postman y necesito hacer todas las rutas como comandos, para solo usar una ruta y que en el body solo envíe una variable y lo que vaya en esa variable sea lo que mande a las demás funciones, pero cuando trato de hacer var variable = rec.body.split("-");
me lanza error y dice "[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]TypeError: req.body.split is not a function"

Comment: si estás usando express.bodyparser entonces `req.body` no es un string sino un objeto. Sería más eficiente que debuguearas lo que contiene tú mismo

Comment: tal y como dice @ffflabs, si estas utilizando algun middleware para poder leer archivos json, entonces no seria una funcion ese `split` que utilizas, El método `split()` divide un ` String` en una lista ordenada de subcadenas, coloca estas subcadenas en una matriz y devuelve la matriz. La división se realiza buscando un patrón; donde el patrón se proporciona como primer parámetro en la llamada al método.

Comment: otro punto a tener en cuenta, no es buena practica tener solamente un endpoint para manejar toda la lógica del backend, podrías utilizar graphql para poder realizar algo parecido

Comment: tengo que hacerlo de esa manera porque así me lo pidió mi profesor, y aún no encuentro una forma de realizar esto que pide, alguna sugerencia o un tema para investigar y que me ayude?